# CSS Styling both img and paragraph child elements

Tags: css, margin

I'm having issues with my 2 child elements both being affected from styles applied to each other. I'm just trying to line up the one with the other better vertically.

I pretty much just went to move the img down a few pixels to line up with the

content. Any css thing I'm missing here?

```
  <div id='fileIcon' class='fileIcon'>
    <img src='images/Google-Chrome-Logo.svg' class="iconImg"></img>
    <p id='fileName'>TestingFileName.pdf</p>
  </div>


  
  .fileIcon {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .iconImg {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
  
  #fileName {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` on your `display: inline-block` elements will center them vertically with each other. `position: relative` and `top: +/- (number)px` will also let you move an element without affecting the page flow.

Comment: Thank you! Handy tip... appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add vertical-align: middle to your image (and forget about `</img>` closing tag)

```css
  .fileIcon {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .iconImg {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  #fileName {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <div id='fileIcon' class='fileIcon'>
    <img src='' class="iconImg">
    <p id='fileName'>TestingFileName.pdf</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Worked great